# Add a class or id to the homepage before the page loads

Tags: magento2, php, home-page

How can I add a class or id to a magento 2 homepage before the page loads? I need the page to render with the class in place, not added after it loads.

Comment: do you want to add on `body` tag ?

Comment: Yes, ideally the html or body tag. I can add classes easily with javascript, but then there is short delay when loading and new styles I want to use flash.